# Java method inheritance problem when overloading the method

Tags: java, oop

Here is my simple code to check Java inheritance & Method overloading. It gives compile error in my IDE. Could you please give an idea about this.? Error line commented in the code. If I comment that line program works fine and provide the given output.

```
class Bird {
    void sing() {
        System.out.println("I am Singing");
    }
}
class Peacock extends Bird {
    void sing() {
        System.out.println("I am Singing COO COO");
    }

    public void sing(String adverb) {
        System.out.println("I am Singing " + adverb);
    }
}
public class OverLoadingDemo {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Bird bird = new Peacock();
        bird.sing();//This return I am Singing COO COO
        bird.sing("Loudly");//ERROR The method sing() in the type Bird is not applicable for the arguments (String)
    }
}
```

Comment: If you want to call the `sing(String)` method, you need to call it on a type of variable which has that method. `Bird` does not. Even though at runtime your variable holds a reference to an object which does have that method, it's the type at compile-time that counts when resolving the method.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The Java compiler sees that the type of the `bird` variable is `Bird`, and doesn't know that you are planning to store a reference to a `Peacock` in that variable.  Since the `Bird` class does not have a method called `sing` that takes a `String` as an argument, it gives you an error.

If the `Bird` class had a `sing` method that took a `String` as an argument, then this code would compile.  Even better, at runtime, it would use the version of the `sing` method (with a `String` argument) that was defined in the `Peacock` class since the variable `bird` would actually hold a `Peacock` object at that point.

Answer (score 2):

When you assign an object to the type of it's ancestors or interfaces, only the methods of the ancestor hierarchy or interface are visible to the object.

In your case a `Peacock` is a `Bird` so it knows about `Peacock` things and `Bird` things.  But a `Bird` object (even if assigned from a `Peacock` object) only knows about `Bird` things that are common to all `Birds`.  Hence, it won't know (and can't tell) that it is a `Peacock`.

This is the `is-a` relationship.  A `Peacock` `is-a` `Bird` in all cases.  But a `Bird` is not a `Peacock` in all cases.